# GanttBarFormat Function VB.NET in MS Project

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I have a custom ribbon setup in MS Project that I want to use to format a Gantt chart item. When the code runs by clicking the Ribbon's button control, the row is selected (as anticipated), but the task's Gantt chart appearance does not change.

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks!

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        ' MAKE THE ACTIVE APPLICATION ACCESSIBLE GLOBALLY ACCESSIBLE 
        ThisApplication = Me.Application
    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Public Class Ribbon1
    Private Sub btnBlackDiamond_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnBlackDiamond.Click
        ThisApplication.SelectRow()
        ThisApplication.GanttBarFormat(TaskID:=3, StartShape:=PjBarEndShape.pjDiamond, StartType:=PjBarType.pjSolid, StartColor:=PjColor.pjRed)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `TaskID` argument:

```
Public Class Ribbon1
    Private Sub btnBlackDiamond_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnBlackDiamond.Click
        ThisApplication.GanttBarFormat(StartShape:=PjBarEndShape.pjDiamond, StartType:=PjBarType.pjSolid, StartColor:=PjColor.pjRed)
    End Sub
End Class
```